# Jenkins job with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: parameters, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was wondering if there was a way to configure Jenkins to allow a user to input a dynamic number of parameters? Here's a little background on why I want this:

A developer works on a patch for an older release of our software. He then wants to have a dashboard where he can go to input the following things and kick off a build:

- Build Version
- AccuRev stream where work was done
- List of patch files(build artifacts) to deploy

The first two things I have working, but I'm not sure how to tackle the last. Sometimes the list has 2 files on it, sometimes it has 10. I was thinking of having the user input a comma-separated string that contains the files they want and then writing a script to parse it, but that's ugly for the user. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the capabilities of the "Text Parameter". With this you can have multi-line input and it gives you an environment variable with lines separated by a `>`. This will allow me to parse the variable and extract the individual patch files.